# Everytime I create my Events page, it shows up as an archive post instead of an actual page

Tags: posts, custom-post-type-archives

I had an events page on my site's main menu in which I attempted to adjust some css when to my horror, I discovered the page appeared as an archive.

I checked in the specific page in question in the "Pages" container in "WP-Admin". It appears as a page in there. I deleted the page anyway and created a new Events page. Same thing. It appears as post/archive rather than a page.

So my question is how I can turn this post into a page? All of the other menu items appear normally as pages.

Here is the page in question: http://cultmontreal.com/events/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that your theme or a plugin has an override for any page called events. Check your theme folder for `page-events.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! My plugin called EventON had overridden any page called "events", so I changed the page name to listing. It seemed to do the trick.

Thanks for your help.